# NameError / "name is not defined" in Python

Tags: python, nameerror

I am a beginner in Python and I receive this error message: `NameError: name 'z' is not defined`.

My code that causes the error:

```
num = int(input("enter the max: "))
for i in range (2, num):
    is_prime = True
    for z in range (2, i):
        if i % z ==0:
            is_prime = False
    if is_prime:
     print(z)
```

Comment: please format your code

Answer (score 0):

You are using `z` outside the `for z in range (2, i):` block.
The `z`, assuming this is the divisor of the determined non-prime number, can be stored to a variable to output it outside of the `for` block:

```
num = int(input("enter the max: "))
for i in range (2, num):
    is_prime = True
    divisable_by = 0
    for z in range (2, i):
        if i % z ==0:
            is_prime = False
            divisable_by = z
    if is_prime:
        print(divisable_by)
```

---

Using more descriptive variable names, removing the additional variable:

```
max = int(input("enter the max: "))
# print all prime numbers up to (max)
for number in range (2, max):
    divisable_by = 0
    for divisor in range (2, int(math.sqrt(number))):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            is_prime = False
            divisable_by = divisor
    if divisable_by != 0:
        print(divisable_by)
```

*Note: limited the inner loop to `2...squareroot(number to check)` to increase performance by a bit.*